# Is there a way to convert PDF to PDF/A using pure C# (if Telerik cannot support it)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, telerik, pdfa

I'm working on a project, Runs on asp.net MVC which uses Telerik Report designer to create PDF reports. Now I'm seeking for a way to create PDF/A (perhaps version 3) since Telerik does not support this format yet.
I know there are some libraries they support this format. however, I'm looking for a solution to make it using pure C# (and/or scripts) or free trustable libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using Telerik and I wanted to share it maybe it was useful for others.
I just needed to convert the fileObject to stream and then, using these lines, I am able to apply settings (e.g. PDF/A) on my stream.
here's the code:

```
private Stream PdfToPdfa(Stream input)
        {
            PdfFormatProvider provider = new PdfFormatProvider();
            PdfExportSettings settings = new PdfExportSettings();
            settings.ComplianceLevel = PdfComplianceLevel.PdfA3B;
            provider.ExportSettings = settings;
            RadFixedDocument document = provider.Import(input);

            Stream output = new MemoryStream();
            provider.Export(document, output);

            return output;
        }
```

The result on "PDF VALIDATOR ONLINE TOOL":

[checking the pdfa validity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOSbE.jpg)

Good luck :)

Comment: Sounds a bit too easy to me, PDF/A has some requirements like embedding the fonts that you probably can't satisfy by just "marking" the document as PDF/A. Have you actually tried to validate it as PDF/A e.g. with verapdf?

Comment: I have added the result of an online PDF validity check. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but just worth noting that Telerik is not _pure c#_, and is also not _free_. So in the spirit of your questions it's maybe worth marking another answer as the correct one.

Comment: you are right @Jordan. Although I thought `Telerik` does not support it and so, therefore, I was looking for a pure `C#` as an alternative solution. but yeah, the question (and title especially) was not clear. I've updated the question to make it more clear. Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: found a similar question with a solution using iTextSharp:
[Can iTextSharp convert PDF document to PDF/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366851/can-itextsharp-convert-pdf-document-to-pdf-a)

If your .PDFs are not longer than 10 pages, spire.pdf would be a free library you could use, as far as i know. For larger .PDFs you need a license though.

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Conversion/How-to-Convert-PDF-to-PDF/A-in-C-VB.NET.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually, I am asking if there is an easy way or suggestion to handle this conversion by pure C#. BTW, the number of pages is more than 10 and I've been searching for a day and did not find a satisfying solution for that. So this is why I'm asking this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion [.NET PDF library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net) supports converting PDF to PDF/A-1b using C#. Refer the below KB for more information.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9515/how-to-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-1b-using-c-and-vb-net

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.